# Apache Pig from timestamp to date

Tags: datetime, hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm trying to analyze some data with apache pig in amabari

In this specific case I have a problem... I have a column with the timestamp written in this specific format

```
1433306146000

1422814565122
```

with the online converter if I put in input  1433306146000 the output is 08/30/47389 @ 12:06pm (UTC) but this is not true, in fact if I manually delete the last 3 numbers (1433306146) the result is 06/03/2015 @ 4:35am (UTC).

So, ther's a method in pig to delete this last 3 numbers in timestamp column?
And also the main question is : with the function

> GetDay(datetime)

if I pass the timestamp it will work? or there's a different method to produce, from the timestamp, the associate week day?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which converter you have used for your timestamps but [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/) it shows propper format. ToDate operator does not act on the complex data type such as bag. That is why you get an error trying to use it on group. Also sometimes behaviour with chararrays is unpredictable thus rule of thumb is to use long primitive type for timestamps. The code below should work.

```
input=LOAD '..Fra/data/prova/*' AS(old_timestamp:long,timestamp:long);
result=FOREACH input GENERATE 
  GetDay(ToDate(old_timestamp)),
  GetDay(ToDate(timestamp));
DUMP result;
```

Also you can also obviously cast from chararray to long in your case if you do not want to change the schema. Only this will change:

```
result=FOREACH input GENERATE 
  GetDay(ToDate((long)old_timestamp)),
  GetDay(ToDate((long)timestamp));
```

Also be careful that ToDate will ALWAYS needs a milliseconds so if you will cut them off you would expect to see Unix default start time of 1970-01-01 
Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the answer! the result produced is the monthly day (from 1 to 31) but if I only want the week days(from 1 to 7)? for example  1 is sunday... what can i do?

Comment: You can either use macro to convert day to number or go the brutal way and use 7 conditional statements

Comment: how can i use it? I'm a noob...but I tried out this way 
result=FOREACH input GENERATE 
  GetDay(ToDate((long)old_timestamp %7) but it not work!

Comment: It will not work as you want to get specifically weekday. I suggest to write a Python(easier) UDF to extract what you want. There are a lot of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is the offset from 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z in terms of milliseconds.You can pass that milliseconds to [ToDate](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ToDate.html) .It takes Unix timestamp as input and returns datetime object. Once you get the datetime object, you can then use the GetDay function.No need to remove last 3 numbers

```
GetDay(ToDate(1433306146000))
```

Note:If you really want to remove 3 numbers then load the data as chararray and use [SUBSTRING](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#substring) function.

Comment: Hi @inquisitive_mind   thanks for the answer! I tried to do something like this

    y=LOAD '../Fra/mydata/* ' AS    (user_id:chararray,event_id:chararray,timestamp:chararray);
    grp= group y by timestamp;
    result = foreach grp{
    GetDay(ToDate(grp);
    }

    dump result;


First question is how timestamp is recognized by pig, I supposed as chararray, Second is that there's an error (maybe not only one, sorry but I'm a noob) exception during parsing... could you help me to solve the problem?
Thanks

Comment: @Fraangel result = foreach grp generate GetDay(ToDate(group)); dump result;

Comment: I answer you as a comment cause the text was too long

Answer (score 0):

@inquisitive_mind I tried the full string (including the offset) but it not work, the error is:

> "invalid format 1422762920000 is malformed at 0000"

so i tried to use substring in this way

`SUBSTRING grp = FOREACH y GENERATE (timestamp),SUBSTRING(timestamp,0,9);`

and then I stored it into a new file for manipulate it in freedom.The output produced was two colum: in the first it was the original timestamp, in the second it was the new timestamp without the last three chars, So I tried to launch this new script:

```
y=LOAD '..Fra/data/prova/*' as (old_timestamp:chararray,timestamp:chararray);
grp=group y by timestamp;
result=foreach grp generate GetDay(ToDate(group));
dump result;
```

the output is:

> "...invalid format 1422762920 malformed at 0"

So even if I knew that while deleting another char from the previus code I would try so I changed the range of the substring function   (timestamp,0,10). And now i tried to relunch the script but the output produced is (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
I'm desperete!